Parse a search string into words and treat words within double quotes as a single term
I know that if I want to parse a string into separate words, the easiest way is.
This is my string:
The Microsoft business analysis software

Code:
SELECT special_term, display_term 
FROM sys.dm_fts_parser ('"The Microsoft business analysis software"', 1033, 0, 0)

Which returns this:
special_term display_term
------------ ------------
Noise Word   the
Exact Match  microsoft
Exact Match  business
Exact Match  analysis
Exact Match  software

But suppose I have a string that has some of the words enclosed in double quotes like this - string:
The Microsoft "business analysis" software

I want to produce the following:
special_term display_term
------------ ------------
Noise Word   the
Exact Match  microsoft
Exact Match  business analysis
Exact Match  software

Is there a reasonable way to do this in SQL Server?

"the easiest way is" Is it? What's wrong with STRING_SPLIT?

I'm using SSMS 19.1. And STRING_SPLIT gives me this: Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 51
'string_split' is not a recognized built-in function name.

SSMS version is like saying you're using windows 11. SQL Server version is what's important, run: select @@version to find out

Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP3-GDR) (KB5029186) - 13.0.6435.1 (X64)   Jul 30 2023 19:53:42   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Web Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0  (Build 14393: ) (Hypervisor)
And the compatibility level is 120 (which is why I don't see SPLIT_STRING. Though it wouldn't have helped anyway, I don't think, because the documentation doesn't show it being able to make exceptions for phrases in quotes.

You can parse string with recursive query.

We can "temporarily" replace spaces by some symbol (_) in quoted phrases and replace back after splitting.
Phrase "business analysis" -> business_analysis ->business analysis.
sys.dm_fts_parser output this "words" as Exact Match.
See example



id
sentence




1
 The Microsoft "business analysis" software And other "helpful programs"


2
But suppose I have a string that has "some of the words" enclosed in double quotes like this - string



with data as(
  select 1 id
    ,'The Microsoft "business analysis" software And other "helpful programs"' sentence
  union all
  select 2 id
    ,'But suppose I have a string that has "some of the words" enclosed in double quotes like this - string'
)

Recursive replace ' ' by '_' in quoted phrases and remove"
,r as(
  select 0 lvl,id
     ,case when charindex('"',sentence)>0 
         and charindex('"',sentence,charindex('"',sentence)+1)>0
       then left(sentence,charindex('"',sentence)-1)
         +replace(substring(sentence,charindex('"',sentence)+1
            ,charindex('"',sentence,charindex('"',sentence)+1)-charindex('"',sentence)-1)
           ,' ','_')
       +right(sentence,len(sentence)-charindex('"',sentence,charindex('"',sentence)+1))
      else sentence
      end sentence
  from data
  union all
  select lvl+1,id
     ,case when charindex('"',sentence)>0 
         and charindex('"',sentence,charindex('"',sentence)+1)>0
       then substring(sentence,1,charindex('"',sentence)-1)
         +replace(substring(sentence,charindex('"',sentence)+1
            ,charindex('"',sentence,charindex('"',sentence)+1)-charindex('"',sentence)-1)
           ,' ','_')
       +substring(sentence,charindex('"',sentence,charindex('"',sentence)+1)+1,100)
      else sentence
      end sentence
  from r
  where charindex('"',sentence)>0 
)
select id,occurrence,special_term,replace(display_term,'_',' ')display_term 
       --,source_term ,group_id,phrase_id
FROM (select *,row_number()over(partition by id order by lvl desc)rn from r)r
cross apply  sys.dm_fts_parser ('"'+r.sentence+'"',1033,0,0)
where rn=1

Output



id
occurrence
special_term
display_term




1
1
Noise Word
the


1
2
Exact Match
microsoft


1
3
Exact Match
business analysis


1
4
Exact Match
software


1
5
Noise Word
and


1
6
Noise Word
other


1
7
Exact Match
helpful programs


2
1
Noise Word
but


2
2
Exact Match
suppose


2
3
Noise Word
i


2
4
Noise Word
have


2
5
Noise Word
a


2
6
Exact Match
string


2
7
Noise Word
that


2
8
Noise Word
has


2
9
Exact Match
some of the words


2
10
Exact Match
enclosed


2
11
Noise Word
in


2
12
Exact Match
double


2
13
Exact Match
quotes


2
14
Noise Word
like


2
15
Noise Word
this


2
16
Exact Match
string




Wow. I have to try this. Thank you so much.

Please try following solution leveraging SQL Server's XML and XQuery functionality.
It will work starting from SQL Server 2012 onwards.
It is using words tokenization where words are separated by space.
As a result of casting, an intermediate XML looks as follows:
<root>
  <r>The</r>
  <r>Microsoft</r>
  <r>"business</r>
  <r>analysis"</r>
  <r>software</r>
</root>

A heavy lifting is happening inside the XQuery FLWOR expression.
SQL
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, words VARCHAR(1024));
INSERT @tbl (words) VALUES
('The Microsoft "business analysis" software');
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
    , z.value('.', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS result
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT TRY_CAST('<root><r><![CDATA[' + 
    REPLACE(words, SPACE(1), ']]></r><r><![CDATA[') + 
    ']]></r></root>' AS XML).query('
    for $x in /root/r/text()
         let $pos := count(root/r[. << $x])
         let $token1 := $x cast as xs:token?
         let $length1 := string-length($token1)
         let $token2 := (/root/r[$pos + 1]/text())[1] cast as xs:token?
         let $length2 := string-length($token2)
      return if (substring($token1,1,1)="""" and substring($token2,$length2,1)="""") 
         then <r>{data((substring($token1,2,100), substring($token2,1,$length2 - 1)))}</r>
         else if (substring($token1,$length1,1)="""") then ()
         else <r>{$token1}</r> 
')) AS t1(x)
CROSS APPLY x.nodes('/r') AS t2(z);

Output



id
words
result




1
The Microsoft "business analysis" software
The


1
The Microsoft "business analysis" software
Microsoft


1
The Microsoft "business analysis" software
business analysis


1
The Microsoft "business analysis" software
software




I'm going to try this as well. Both of these answers are using SQL that is way beyond my general knowledge, so I'm going to try them out and see if I can break either of them. Thank you so much.

Hmm... the problem with this solution is that it only preserves the quoted phrase if there's a single quoted phrase in the string. For something like 'This is "the best" example "of them all", right?', it'll break up the words in the second quoted phrase.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
